# CakePHP 4 - bake won't let me use a different database connection to 'default'

Tags: php, cakephp, cakephp-4.x

CakePHP 4.0.8

In my `config/app_local.php` I have 2 different databases defined:

```
'Datasources' => [

    'default' => [
        'host' => 'localhost',
        'username' => '***',
        'password' => '***',
        'database' => 'db1',
        'url' => env('DATABASE_URL', null),
    ],

    'interface_db' => [
        'host' => 'localhost',
        'username' => '***',
        'password' => '***',
        'database' => 'db2',
        'url' => env('DATABASE_URL', null),
    ]
]
```

When I execute `php bin/cake.php bake model` it will list tables in the `default` database configuration, i.e. any tables in `db1`.

I can't change to `interface_db` and bake models for `db2`. In CakePHP 3 I used the `-c` flag with bake to change the connection, e.g. `bin/cake.php bake model -cinterface_db`

This gives an error:

```
2020-06-05 12:14:53 Error: [Cake\Datasource\Exception\MissingDatasourceConfigException] The datasource configuration "interface_db" was not found. in .../vendor/cakephp/cakephp/src/Datasource/ConnectionManager.php on line 203
```

The array key `interface_db` defines the connection to `db2`.

Why is this occurring? It used to work in Cake 3.

Comment: I think this is a bug in CakePHP 4 so have opened it as an Issue on https://github.com/cakephp/bake/issues/691

Answer (score 2):

same bug for me, but fixed with app_local.php:

1. add

```
use Cake\Database\Driver\Mysql;
use Cake\Database\Connection;
```

before the return statement

2. add className & driver to the config:

```
'className' => Connection::class,
'driver' => Mysql::class,
```

so in your case :

```
    'interface_db' => [
            'host' => 'localhost',
            'className' => Connection::class,
            'driver' => Mysql::class,
            'username' => '***',
            'password' => '***',
            'database' => 'db2',
            'url' => env('DATABASE_URL', null),
        ]
```

and it will work.

className & drivers are defined into app.php for de default, but not for your custom one.